# Titan Warn: Query requires iterating over all vertices [(name <> null)]

Tags: java, hbase, titan

I have used below code

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
PropertyKey name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(String.class).make();
mgmt.buildIndex("name",Vertex.class).addKey(name).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
```

while retrieving data from graph i am getting this warning,

```
TransactionalGraph tx = g.newTransaction();
Iterator vertex=tx.query().has("name").vertices.iterator();
```

Entire graph is traversed to fetch the vertices instead of indexed vertices.
Please suggest changes.

Comment: what version of titan?

Comment: I am using titan-0.5.2-hadoop2

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the Titan 1.0 [indexing documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_index), but its description for composite indexes is applicable to 0.5.2 also.

> Composite indexes are very fast and efficient but limited to equality
>   lookups for a particular, previously-defined combination of property
>   keys.

Composite indexes are for exact match key-value retrievals. Your query should contain the property value you are looking for in order to leverage the index.

```
tx.query().has("name", "userRaj").vertices.iterator()
```

The way you have it coded in your question, it has to scan all vertices that have the property `name` because it is not attempting to match on any particular value (i.e. `null`).

```
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(name <> null)]. For better performance, use indexes
```

If you're doing new Titan development, I'd recommend you move up to 1.0 since there won't be any more releases on the 0.5.x stream.

Comment: I want to fetch all vertices with key=name. I tried graph.indexQuery("name","v.name:*").vertices().iterator(); but it is giving illegalArgumentException

Comment: Because now you're trying to do a direct index query which is supposed to be used against a mixed index (external indexing backend), not a composite index. http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/direct-index-query.html